# Maintaining order using union in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. some records of first table(table p) are present in second table(table c).
My mission is to fetch some data from table c on some condition(maintaining certain order) and append the remaining entries from table p.I am using the below query.

```
select * 
from(
with c_data as (select pId from table c where eid=1234 and pId is not null order by id desc)
select p.id,1 as filter
from table p and p.id in (select distinct pId from c_data)
union 
select p.id,2 
from table p where p.eid=1234 and p.id not in (select distinct pId from c_data ))order by filter
```

Now the test data is as below:
output of first query, run separately

```
p.id
----
586
568
589
854
741
254
789
954
365
```

output of second query run seperately

```
981
555
```

as I am applying "`p.id not in (select distinct pId from c_data )`".

But as I am appending this part, the order of the first part of the query is getting tempered

Comment: I didn't read your question but based only on its title, the answer is described in the [documentation of `UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html). Have you read it?

Comment: @axiac I read it now,if you see i have tried to apply the filter in query. But not sure, how to achieve the behavior

Comment: The only order you specified here is by `filter`. Which order you mean by "(maintaining certain order)" might be clear to you, but it is neither clear to us (as "certain order" can mean anything), nor is it clear to the MySQL server (as he only does what he is told, and you didn't tell him to order by anything but `filter`, so he doesn't order by anything but `filter`). You will need to be more precise in describing the order you want (either to us or the MySQL server).

Comment: ID is the primary key in table c. when data is getting inserted in table c from table p, an sequence val(id) is getting generated. So when I am trying to fetch data from table c, I am querying on latest data.Hence

 "select pId from table c where eid=1234 and pId is not null order by id desc"

Comment: The fact that `c_data` might be order somehow does not order your output. `c_data` is like a phonebook (ordered by last name). If I ask you to check if "Shubha", "Aristoteles" and "George Washington" are in the book and only give me those that are, this does not tell me in which order you want these 3 names. To order your result, you have to write `order by xxx` on the outmost `select`, otherwise you get them in the order MySQL prefers. If you need help identifying that column, please add some sampledata and describe the order you want. It sounds a bit as if you can/have to use a `join` here.